# Android soft keyboard: only top row of keys work

Tags: android, soft-keyboard, inputconnection

*This question already has an answer, it's a contibution to SO question base.*

In my custom view I implemented the `onCreateInputConnection` method like so:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    BaseInputConnection baseInputConnection =
            new BaseInputConnection(this, false);

    outAttrs.actionLabel = null;
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL;
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE;

    return baseInputConnection;
}
```

But for some strange reason, in default AOSP keyboard in Android 5 **only top row of keys work**.
Note that I have a landscape layout. If I switch to portrait, it starts to work properly. Other keyboards also work right.

Comment: StackOverflow says 'You can accept your own answer in 2 days', so I can't accept my own answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had to change this line:

```
outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;
```

`IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI` is a flag to prevent keyboard from going to fullscreen. But it doesn't go to fullscreen already (as my input type is `TYPE_NULL`).

Bottom line, it's a bug with Android 5.